# How to check the system did a graceful shutdown?

Tags: hardware, power-management

How to check the system did a graceful shutdown?

Is there any log in `/var/log/messages` to indicate the last time shutdown is a graceful shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very Linux distro/Unix specific. As for Fedora 33 that's (no `/var/log/messages` - these are journalctl messages):

```
Nov 09 21:22:16 zen systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Nov 09 21:22:16 zen systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Nov 09 21:22:16 zen systemd-journald[1169]: Journal stopped
```